# Fixing classes that use Disposable stuff

Tags: c#, dispose

Given this example code, what is the best way to fix it so that the bitmap gets disposed:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.ShowDialog();
form.Dispose();

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Class2 _class2;
    public Form1()
    {
        _class2 = new Class2();
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    private Bitmap _bitmap;
    public Class2()
    {
        _bitmap = new Bitmap(100,100);
    }
}
```

I started by putting `_bitmap.Dispose()` in the destructor of Class2.  But I don't think that will really work right.

Do I need to have Class2 implement `IDisposable`?  Then attach to the `Disposed` event of `Form1` and call dispose on `_class2`.

That seems like the best way, but I want to make sure it is the right way.

Comment: Make class 2 have implement `IDisposable` but don't give it a destructor/finalizer. Bitmap already has a finalizer and that's enough.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would implement to have Class2 implement `IDisposable`.Or you can do something like

```
public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        using (Bitmap _bitmap = new Bitmap(100,100)) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea.  Alas, this is a very very simplified version of my class.  "Bitmap" is actually several disposable resources allocated by different classes and are then used through out the life of the class.  (Though where possible I have used a using)

Comment: @Vaccano: If they are used throughout the life of the class and should be disposed of at the end, just make the class disposable.

Answer (score 1):

That is the way I would do it; I believe it's the "correct" approach.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `using` block along with Kumar's suggestion of having Class2 implement `IDisposable`?

```
    public Form1()
    {
       using(Class2 _class2 = new Class2()){
          //do stuff with _class2
          //dispose will automatically get called when using is exited
       }
    }
```

The `using` block will ensure that `Dispose()` is called on Class2, and in there you'll properly dispose of your `Bitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement IDisposable in Class2. In addition, you might like to override Form.Dispose(bool):

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing && (_class2 != null)) _class2.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```